# FloatingActionBar cannot show out

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-design-library

I have face the problem that I cannot use these 2 rows in my apps. I want to make the `FloatingActionBar` show between the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the RecycleView. Anyone know what is the problem of this? If I didn't put these 2 rows it's by default place at top left and can show out after run in phone. If I put it and run, it cannot show on my phone.

```
<!--app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"-->
<!--app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"-->
```

**XML File**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/purplewhite"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/search_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/alice_blue" />

    <!--app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"-->
    <!--app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPil4.png)

Comment: Why are you using `<!-- -->` in your xml, it means you are commenting it out.

Comment: ya...currently put inside also cannot show
then i it comment first below <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header2"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/search_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/alice_blue" />

<!--app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"-->
<!--app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"-->
```

Comment: hmmm, still not the one i'm actually want. I have add in the image1 in the title for reference for the places of floatingActionBar that I want to place.